# Indexing in a pair of lists

Tags: python, types

```
list1 = ["M", "na", "i", "Ke"]
list2 = ["y", "me", "s", "lly"]
list3 = [i + j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
print(list3)
```

Goal is to print "My" "name" "is" "Kelly" as list 3
In this situation, I am not sure what i and j represent. If zip is a function to add elements in the two lists, what does j in zip mean?

I tried to do a for loop

```
list1 = ["M", "na", "i", "Ke"]
list2 = ["y", "me", "s", "lly"]
for item in list1:
    list3 =list1[item]+list2[item]
    print(list3)
```

But I kept getting this error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Also, the first code seems like it does exactly what you want.  Why did you need to write the second code at all?  What is the problem?

Comment: Oh I just included the first code because I was confused about what i and j did. Also sorry for the late reply. I just signed up on this website.

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `j` are loop variables that you create. You can call them anything you want.

You might want to start with some simpler loops like this to understand what is going on:

```
for i in ["a", "b", "c"]:
  print(i)
```

Probably worth reading a basic Python tutorial too. There are a bazillion gajillion of them on the web.

Comment: How many!? Really!?

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` is probably what you want here, as described in your original question. But, if you must use indices, you want to iterate over the indices of the list and use `.append()` to build up the list:

```
list1 = ["M", "na", "i", "Ke"]
list2 = ["y", "me", "s", "lly"]
list3 = []
for idx in range(len(list1)):
    list3.append(list1[idx]+list2[idx])
print(list3)
```

This outputs:

```
['My', 'name', 'is', 'Kelly']
```

Comment: Or, you know, use `zip` like in the listcomp and write Pythonic code. If you're ever generating indices solely for the purpose of indexing, you're either writing good C or bad Python.

Comment: I got the impression that they didn’t want to use `zip`, so I avoided using it. You’re not wrong though.